# How to Throttle CoreMIDI in Objective-C

Tags: ios, multithreading

My CoreMIDI connection on iOS is apparently fast enough to handle ANYTHING that hits it... if I'm just doing some simple object creation and `NSLog`. In the UI, I don't have time to handle everything that comes in. The UI would blow up, or just finish processing too late.

However, I need to do real processing and UI display in response to CoreMIDI inputs. What I'd like is to process the **latest** messages every, say, 1ms or 2ms. I've been doing this with a collection that gets emptied by a timer-fired method every 1ms (`processFromServerAsync`). One problem is that some messages might fall through the cracks, I think, if I grab and substitute:

```
NSDictionary *queueCopy = [self.queue copy];
// here the dictionary could get messages not in the queue copy!
self.queue = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

I realize that I could handle this by synchronizing with a lock, which is easy to screw up:

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *)messageQueue {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (!messageQueue_)
            self.messageQueue = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        return messageQueue_;
    }
}

-(NSDictionary*)clearMessageQueueAndReturnCopy {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (!messageQueue_)
            return [NSDictionary dictionary];
        NSDictionary *retVal = [messageQueue_ copy];
        self.messageQueue = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

**However, I'm not convinced that I'm even handling this in the correct way. How is throttling typically done (even outside of Obj-C)?** I surely cannot process all those messages in the UI nor the program.

Comment: @TimKemp if you slide four sliders as fast as you can on external MIDI hardware, it's NOT too much for CoreMIDI, but it's a LOT to do any logic processing. Gotta be ready for that.

Comment: OK I got you, that is a lot of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some well-established patterns for throttling streams of incoming data. This comes up a lot in finance, where you might have a data feed throwing 100K messages/sec at a system.

You employ a sliding window mechanism to discard redundant messages while ensuring that the client has the latest possible copy of the data. You set your window up over some time period (a few milliseconds) then set up a queue for each data stream (meaning a particular CC, midi note etc.) You start a global timer when the first message comes in. You send that message to the client immediately. If anything else comes in during the window you push it to its queue. The queue has just one entry - the latest value - so you overwrite the queued value with each subsequent update. When the timer ticks (the window is over) you send the latest message out to the client. Then, you send the next message out as soon as it comes in, start a new window and repeat. This gives a reasonable balance between swamping the client and avoiding aliasing of update intervals to the timer window. Aliasing is less of an issue with 1-2ms intervals so a cruder rigid timer approach might work for you.

The critical thing is ensuring that you have separate windows for each data stream. You can't risk overwriting or ignoring, say, a note off because a control change came in. One timer, one single-entry queue per Midi message number.

Comment: So in the finance example you have one data stream per stock symbol, for instance? And you're running as many timers as data streams? Also, now I'm concerned that my processing cannot finish in the allotted time... I guess I have to handle that by rescheduling only when I'm done processing....

Comment: It's actually one stream per attribute per symbol, eg Vodafone Bid, Vodafone Offer are two streams. Conflation is often for the screen though, so you're using a window of 250-500ms. I've edited the answer because it's not clear that you use just one shared timer. The 'streams' are more like single-entry queues where you only keep the latest copy of that particular datum.

Comment: Hmmm... here the window size is MUCH smaller and processing time might exceed window size, so... what, just forget about a window and reschedule as soon as possible?

Comment: If processing time exceeds the window size then your throttling window size is too small. Having said that, if you're just updating a GUI then you can only do that roughly once every 16ms anyway (at 60fps). A simpler scheme is to keep the latest value for each MIDI message number in memory, then atomically publish it to the consumer side once every $window seconds and clear it. An associative array keyed on message number & control change number would do the storage part, then you have a timer to flush it.

Comment: Thanks muchly, Tim. This is all beginning to make sense. Separating out the display part (calling setNeedsDisplay too often locks up the whole app temporrily) and thinking of it in terms of FPS really helps. This way I'll probably have this entire process running at two velocities (both throttled): processing the MIDI info coming in, and then a slower velocity (like 16 or 32ms) just calling the setNeedsDisplay on all the relevant players.

Comment: Np. Good luck with it. You may find that you only need to throttle the display part.

Comment: part 2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123491/throttle-sending-in-coremidi Thanks Tim!